# Variance of estimator two forms

Tags: statistics

How does my stats teacher go from

$$Var(B_{0})=\sigma^{2} \left(\frac{\sum x^2_{j}}{nS_{xx}}\right)$$ to $$\sigma^{2} \left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\bar x^2}{Sxx}\right)$$

I have trouble seeing how they are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum(x_{j}-\bar{x})^2=\sum x_{j}^{2}-n \bar{x}^{2}$ $\implies$ $S_{xx}=\sum x_{j}^{2}-n \bar{x}^{2}$ or $\sum x_{j}^{2}= S_{xx}+n \bar{x}^{2}$

$Var(B_{0}) = \sigma^{2}\left(\dfrac{\sum x_{j}^2}{nS_{xx}}\right)=\sigma^{2}\left(\dfrac{S_{xx}+ n\bar{x}^{2}}{nS_{xx}}\right)=\sigma^{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{\bar{x}^2}{S_{xx}}\right)$